How to download latest open source magento
How to download latest open source magento version, not from GitHub, manual download.

You can download Magento2 in 3 possible ways
Composer – Most recommended solution for Magento 2 download
Github – Mostly used by developers
Archive – Can be downloaded in zip/tar format
Please check here for more details.

Any other website gives zip format to download.

check here https://www.mageplaza.com/download-magento/

It will redirect to github, instead you can use magefan, i posted as answered, you can download directly.

Found It.
Following site offer zip file.
https://magefan.com/magento-download/download-magento-247
